# Using regex to search for a certain string

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm having some problems with understanding how regular expressions work.
I am using Autolocation with Tasker on my android and have marked 2 types of locations with the patterns

> [Safe] theNameOfTheSafePlace

and

> [Danger] theNameOfTheDanger

I am trying to find out if the area I'm in is marked as safe or dangerous. I have tried using regex with the name

> /[Safe/](.+)

but it doesn't recognize it.

What am I doing wrong and what would be the correct way to write this expression?

Thanks

Comment: post the code that you're using

Comment: the above is all the code I'm using. It's an empty stringfield inside of autovoice in Tasker, which is then checked against using regex. If there were anymore code, I would post it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using backslashes `\` to escape the `[]` not forward slashes.

Try:

```
\[safe\](.+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be "\[Safe\](.+)"   instead of   "/[Safe/](.+)"  ?